# if-else behaviour without braces: How is the answer 7 and not 6?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public class inc {
    public static void main (String []args) {
       inc.sixOrSeven();
    }

    public static void sixOrSeven() {
        byte q=5;
        if (q==5)
            q+=1;
        else 
            q--;
            q++;
        System.out.println(q);
    }
}
```

I'm new to computer science and my teacher taught me a few concepts about increments and decrements. When I ran the program, the console showed me the answer is 7. But I began doubting the answer itself. Since `q=5` `5+1=6` and if q isn't 5 then `5+1-1=5`? How can the answer be 7.

Comment: else only contains  `q--` , `q++` will be executed every time

Comment: Code does nothing. `main` is empty

Comment: @PavneetSingh True. Still the main method is empty, so there should be no output

Answer (score 3):

It would be 6 if you wrote:

```
    public static void sixOrSeven() {
        byte q=5;
        if (q==5) {
            q+=1;
        }
        else {
            q--;
            q++;
        }
       System.out.println(q);
    }
```

According to the specification:

[image]

and [statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5), it can be written as:

```
Statement:
    StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
    (...)
StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement:
    Block
    (...)
(...)
```

So we end up with:

```
if (Expression) 
    single statement (can be a block)
else
    single statement (can be a block)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the comments

```
public static void sixOrSeven() {
    byte q=5; // q is 5
    if (q==5) // q == 5 true
        q+=1; // q = q + 1 which is q = 5 + 1 = 6. That means Now q = 6
    else  // As if was true so this else is ignored
        q--;
    q++; // q++ means q = q + 1 = 6 + 1 = 7; So Now q = 7
    System.out.println(q); // print q which is 7
}
```

> If-else logic if [if or else] doesn't have any { } . Then next immediate single statement will be considered as under that if or else

Comment: What do you quote?